# expected values determined with model parameters estimated from a nlme analysis

Tags: r, mixed-model

I'm kind new into nonlinear mixed model theory and I've seen that you cannot determine expected values of your response variable by simply inserting the estimated parameters into your model equation, because the model is nonlinear in the random components. Why is that? What is the theory behind that? And, what should I do when I want to insert the parameters back to the model? For example, let's say I have the Brody growth curve:

```
Wit = A - (A-Wo)e^-kti
```

where, W is weight of individual i at time t, A, Wo, and k are parameters. Once I run a nlme analysis (e.g. with nlme/lme4 in R), what should I consider to put the estimated parameters back in the model so I can get predicted values of Wit?

Many thanks.